# JSON Normalize fails for Nested Json array abruptly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

For below nested json, the array is not getting normalized using below code

```
import pandas as pd
import json

def on_input(data):
    df = pd.read_json(data)df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(data))
    api.send("output", df.to_json(orient="records"))

api.set_port_callback("input1", on_input)
```

I also tried `max_level` and then `record_path` but no luck :(

Is there any way to normalise the json to check iF Then else condition & then updated suffix for column field and eventually updated to DB with no duplicates? Here `header.poNumber` and `data.id` are primary keys/unique identifiers.

**Input**

```
[
   {
      "header.poNumber":"9023496",
      "data.id":"10013459",
      "message.source":[
         {
            "createSource":null,
            "timeStamp":"2023-05-12T19:30:00.0000000+02:00",
            "type":"full"
         },
         {
            "createSource":"testdev",
            "timeStamp":"2023-05-11T19:30:00.0000000+02:00",
            "type":"ordersEstimated"
         },
         {
            "createSource": "event",
            "timeStamp":"2023-05-12T12:30:00.0000000+01:00",
            "type":"ordersCreated"
         }
      ],
      "message.time":[
         {
            "timeSource":"UTC",
            "typeId":"full"
         },
         {
            "timeSource":"IST",
            "typeId":"actual"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**Output**

| header.poNumber | data.id | message.source.timestamp1 | message.source.type1 | message.source.timestamp2 | message.source.type2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9023496 | 10013459 | 2023-05-11T19:30:00.0000000+02:00 | ordersEstimated | 2023-05-12T12:30:00.0000000+01:00 | ordersCreated |

Comment: Is that the desired result or the result you're actually getting?

Comment: that is desired result i needed. So require help.

Comment: Why isn't `message.time` in the result? Or the first element in `message.source`?